# Creating a Copy of SSRS Site

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a production SQL Server Reporting Services site called `http://server/reports`.

Now I want to redevelope this, without causing any downtime. I would like to copy the whole site and point it at `http://server/reports2`.

Here I can change what the user will see before evetually pointing the new site back at `http://server/reports`.

Is this possible

Comment: [Copy SSRS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/91e1ec79-e2b1-4d7c-8890-83a131511e39) What are you trying to change?

Comment: Do you mean you to create a copy of the production report manager site on the same production server? Or a different server? You will need to create copies of the Report Manager databases as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can go into SSRS config and choose a new site name.  All Programs>SQL Server 2008>Config Tools>SSRS Configuration Manager.  It opens up a little admin site>Click 'Report Manager URL' on the left pane provided you have the credentials to get in.  You can change your website and web service site here.

However that may wipe out your old site as I am not certain if that would work except for 'moving' a site.  If you want two sites you will have to work with 'Scale-out Deployment' most likely which is a different problem all together.